# Is there any way to add elements end of the line with the help of Bat convertor

Tags: batch-file

I have a situation/requirement to add a field to every end of the line with the separator of comma(,) in .csv/txt file, but facing problem as it taking lots of time to completing the process. There is 2 million lines in a file.

.Bat file i have wrote:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "*file_name*.csv"') do (
>>"file_name.csv" echo.%%a,field1,field2)
```

How can I reduce the execution time/process it with one enter only?

Comment: How many csv files? what spec machine do you have? if the files are large or many files to process then `type` will take some time to complete each file. I would anyway suggest this version of your code instead `(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "*file_name*.csv"') do
echo(%%a,field1,field2)>file_name.csv`

Comment: Hi Gerhard, Thank you so much for your suggestion, I have  4-5 files and also have a sufficient space on my machine. but the piece of code you have shared its not working.

Comment: Can you clarify to us what you think the end of the line means? because, your code appears to sugges it to mean the beginning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.
First, you just **append** new lines to your original `csv` file. I understand your new file should have the same amount of lines as the old file, not twice the number.
Second: with `>>"file_name.csv" echo...` your computer opens the target file for each line, reads through the whole file to reach the end, writes a single line and closes the file again before opening it again, etc. etc. etc. That's time-consuming. Instead, redirect the whole loop - the target file is opened once (no need to read the whole file, as `>` means "overwrite"), write all the data in one go and close the file. That should give it a big boost with large files.

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "file_name.csv"') do echo %%a,field1,field2)>filename.new
move /y filename.new filename.csv
```

I understand you have several files to process. Use another `for` loop to process all of them:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "file_name.csv"') do ( 
    echo %%a,field1,field2
  ))>"%%~nf.new"
  move /y "%%~nf.new" "%%f"
)
```

(Hint: you don't need the dot with the `echo` command (the string will never be empty). Removing it saves you a little time per line)